# Aplicação em codeigniter não funciona com o mongodb

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb

Tenho um sistema em codeigniter e eu não consigo fazer requisições usando a lib mongo_db. Nao é possivel conectar, autenticar e, ou buscar dados do banco de dados. Acredito que a biblioteca esta corrompida, pois o sistema aparentemente esta ok e pelo shell eu acesso normalmente os dados para leitura ou gravação.

erro vindo da view  https://prnt.sc/jivefw

código fonte do erro acima  https://prnt.sc/jivd8g

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). O ideal é que adicione tanto o código quanto o erro como texto, o editor possui ferramentas para isso. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Acrescente também a biblioteca que está utilizando para se conectar o codeigniter com o mongodb, e troque as imagens do código pelo código em texto.